# ArcMap ModelBuilder iterate Raster and Feature Class with Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, iteration

[image: Main and Sub models]

In our model we calculate raster datasets with the cost distance and the raster calculator. We want to multiply these with a field value from the table `testbezirk`. We have already tried a few things, no error message comes up or ArcMap throws exception and there is no message, but all rasters are multiplied with the last value from the table `testbezirk`. It should be so that the field value (long variable) is calculated from the same row from which the cost distance is calculated. So :

[image: table Testbezirk]

The Test District table has the source items for the cost distance and then the field value `Cyclist` is to be taken from the same row and multiplied by the raster data `p_%Name%`.

We are not getting anywhere and have already tried the whole thing with sub models, but it does not work. Does anyone have an idea?

In detail: the main model contains the sub model cost distance and probability. In the cost distance the feature classes "testbezirk" are iterated with a source raster. The datasets are stored in a geodatabase named "costdistance" by name `cd_%Name%`. In the probability submodel the costdistance datasets are iterated from the "costdistance" geodatabase and calculated using the raster calculator. These raster datasets are then stored in another geodatabase "probability" by name `p_cd_%Name%`.

The datasets from the geodatabase "probability" should now be iterated and multiplied with the corresponding field value "cyclist" from the table "testbezirk", so the field value should also be iterated. Whenever a raster is iterated, the corresponding field value is to be iterated.

Example: `r_p_cd_1 * 66, r_p_cd_2 *51`, etc...

Comment: Is the main model combination of cost distance and probability? "calculate raster datasets with the cost removal and the raster calculator" Can you throw some more light into it?

Comment: I have added to the text.